# How to make a fade in/out slogan with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code that modifies the contents of a div on refresh.

But I also want it to fade in and out a new random text over a set amount of time. I don't know where to start here's my original code:

HTML:

```
<div id="logo" class="container">
    <h1>InsiderIndy</h1>
    <p id="myQuote">Slogan</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myQuotes = new Array();

myQuotes[0] = "Quote1";
myQuotes[1] = "Quote2";
myQuotes[2] = "Quote3"
myQuotes[3] = "Quote4"
myQuotes[4] = "Quote5"
myQuotes[5] = "Quote6"

var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length);

$('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[myRandom]);
</script>
```

Any ideas? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full working example with an adjustable function for fade speed, pause time between rotations, and start position. Also returns back to the beginning when it reaches the end:

EDIT: I read your question too quickly the first time and wrote a function for a sequential rotation. I've updated my answer to include two functions--one for a sequential rotation `startSeq()` and a second for a random rotation `startRandom()`.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GdmQE/)

```
function startSeq(i,iSpeed, iPause) {

    $('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[i]);
    $('#myQuote').fadeIn(iSpeed,function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#myQuote').fadeOut(iSpeed,function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                     if (i++ == myQuotes.length) i =0;
                    startSeq(i,iSpeed,iPause); 
                },iPause);
            });
        },iPause);
    });
}

function startRandom(iSpeed, iPause) {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length);
    $('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[i]);
    $('#myQuote').fadeIn(iSpeed,function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#myQuote').fadeOut(iSpeed,function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    startRandom(iSpeed,iPause); 
                },iPause);
            });
        },iPause);
    });
}

//startSeq(0,1000,1000);
startRandom(1000,1000);
```

Comment: Whoops, missed the 'random order' part of your question. This works, but not exactly what you want...

Comment: This is awesome! But is the random function taken away from this? I kinda wanted to keep that incorporated but if not it is okay, I still appreciate all of this!

Comment: Yeah, I'll modify it for randomness, one sec.

Comment: lol just read your comment :) I'll use this for now until I can get the random to work haha
-- edit --
Thanks!

Comment: There you go! Two functions, one for sequential rotation and another for random rotation.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect! Saved me a lot  of time! Actually I don't believe I could of even achieved this haha! Thanks again.

Comment: I always forget to do that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like jQuery, so...

```
(function quote() {
    var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length);

    $('#myQuote').delay(5000)
                 .fadeOut(500, function() {
                     $(this).text(myQuotes[myRandom])
                            .fadeIn(500, quote);
                  });
})();
```

You should probably take some time and study the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com)

Comment: You should put the text change and the `fadeIn` into a function which gets executed on complete of `fadeOut`.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```javascript
var refreshMillis = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds.
setInterval(function() {
  var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length)
    , $myQuote = $('#myQuote');
  $myQuote.fadeOut(function() {
    $myQuote.html(myQuotes[myRandom]).fadeIn();
  });
}, refreshMillis);
```

Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beku2/).